# How saline were the earth's oceans during the Last Glacial Maximum?

Tags: oceanography, glaciology, ice-age, salinity

[According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saline_water#/media/File:Water_salinity_diagram.png) sea water is 34.7 parts per thousand salt.

Between evaporation and precipitation it seems like this amount is kept largely in equilibrium but, during the last glacial maximum, a lot of this precipitation would have frozen to form glaciers.

Since that precipitation didn't make it into the ocean it stands to reason that this would have increased the salinity of the oceans. And sure, if the amount of water held in the glaciers was a drop in the bucket compared to the water in the oceans then I guess it wouldn't have made much of a difference.

But, [according to USGS](https://pubs.usgs.gov/fs/fs2-00/): "global sea level was about 125 meters below today’s sea level at the last glacial maximum about 20,000 years ago".

This kinda makes me wonder: how saline were the oceans during the last glacial maximum?